# Mongo Collection name gets truncated

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

We have created a Mongo DB using Azure cosmos and imported JSON file into a collection. However when we try to access collection from Java api (MongoTemplate) to read imported json, we encounter an exception stating collection not exist in DB.

When we investigated our code more, we have identified the collection name gets truncated. For Ex:- If I have a collection name with "componentTemplates", but the same is displayed with some strange string like "nentTemplates". Because of this our code is not working and application fails to serve the request.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Just as initial check, Could you please make sure your are following the naming convention. 
Collection names must contain from 1 through 255 characters, and they cannot contain /, \\, #, ?, or a trailing space.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope we were not using any special characters like /, \\, #, ? etc in the collection name. its a collection with name "componentTemplates". so not sure how this is getting truncated.